# PHP find address of relative file in remote URL

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image

I've got a PHP crawler which takes the contents of any URL and reads it. When it comes across code for an image `(img src=)` it finds the source path. What I need to do is, if the path is relative, make it absolute.

If the URL of the page itself is true I can see it is possible to work this out. However many URLs, like those on WordPress sites, have plenty of .htaccess going on.

So lets say I have the page:

```
http://example.com/archives/12/4/page-title/
```

I don't know what this URL really is but I've got a fair guess that '12' and '4' are not directories.

On that page I have img `src="/images/picture/jpg"`. How can I work out the absolute path to that image?

I've searched for two possibilities:

1. Finding out the real URL of a page - can't find anything on this
2. Finding the absolute path of a remote file without using the URL -
   can't find anything on this

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think much too complicated. Don't!

From the outside view you are not interested in any rewriting or the like. The only way to address such an object (for example an image) is the url. This is what the browser does. It combines the base url of the currently loaded page and the relative path to the image. Either that delivers the object, or the url is broken. This is true regardless of how many times and how complicated the server internally will rewrite the request or do other magic things.

That is non of your business and there is no way for you to get around this.

There is not such thing as a "real url" and you have no use of an "absolute path", if such exists at all.

Comment: What you're saying is if the browser sees mysite.com/pretenddirectory/page.html and in it there is img src="/img/image.jpg" if will look for the image at mysite.com/img/image.jpg. But I've created pages like mysite.com/realdirectory/page.html with the same img src and the browser is quite happy to get it from mysite.com/realdirectory/img/image.jpg because it is a relative address. How does the browser know one directory is real and one is false (rewritten thru .htaccess)?

Comment: The browser "knows" nothing, you are thinking too compliated. This is more primitive. To your examples: the first one is ok and makes sense, it is what one would expect. The second one however does not make sense. The browser will certainly _not_ request `mysite.com/realdirectory/img/image.jpg`, instead it would request `mysite.com/img/image.jpg` just as before, since the src attribute does _not_ specify anything relative, but an _absolute_ path. Note the difference: the leading slash (`/`). Without that, then indeed the browser would request `mysite.com/realdirectory/img/image.jpg`.

Comment: Light dawning ... I think. If there is a leading slash the browser works from the root. If there is no leading slash it looks at what is in the URL and is relative to that which, if this was rewritten in .htaccess, would cause the image to fail because there is no such 'real' directory ...

Comment: Yes, basically true. That is just the concept of an 'absolute' versus a 'relative' path. Be it on the web or in the local file system. I'd say the expressions absolute and relative are pretty self explaining, once one got the idea. Some people also speak of absolute or relative urls, but that is total nonsense. A url is always absolute, everything without a protocol scheme and a host name is not an url but a path.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited to correct typo - I hadn't noticed the leading slash on the src in the example]

You have as much information as the browser.  If it sees an image with src `/images/picture/jpg` on a page  `http://example.com/archives/12/4/page-title/` then it will load the image from  `http://example.com/images/picture/jpg`.  If the src has been just `images/picture/jpg`on the same page you would fetch an image from `http://example.com/archives/12/4/page-title/images/picture/jpg`

If those are not "real" pages then the .htaccess must cope with the image URLs as well since that will be the URL the browser calls.  Most of the rewrites in .htaccess are invisible to the user anyway - e.g. it's quite standard for a CMS like Wordpress to redirect everything that does not match a file on the disk to index.php for processing by the CMS but the user still sees their pretty URL.

My experience with wordpress is that it always puts in absolute URLs for images (at least if added via the Wordpress editing system - if you do the HTML yourself then you do it yourself).

Short answer: if you are crawling web pages then you do not need to know the "real" url (which is often just /index.php anyway).  That's the magic of .htaccess

Comment: Umm ... I tried this on one of my pages: http://doodleddoes.com/blog/can-you-seo-for-a-specified-keyword-in-2014/ where the first image has src="/blog/images/posts/keyword-x.jpg". But this doesn't go to http://doodleddoes.com/blog/can-you-seo-for-a-specified-keyword-in-2014/blog/images/posts/keyword-x.jpg. It goes to http://doodleddoes.com/blog/images/posts/keyword-x.jpg. Nothing in .htaccess to tell it to do this for images...

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  The src is `"/blog/images/posts/keyword-x.jpg"`.  The page is on `http://doodleddoes.com/blog/can-you-seo-for-a-specified-keyword-in-2014/` so the full URL for the image (which the browser fetches it from) is `http://doodleddoes.com/blog/images/posts/keyword-x.jpg`. Quite correct (since the src starts with  "/").  [Oops! just seen a typo in my answer related to that.  Will edit.] No need for any .htaccess.  What are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks - between you and arkascha I've got it straight!